# Superset - Chart TABLE : How to set the background color of an entire row (with an hack ? or not)

Tags: javascript, html, apache-superset

Q1- How to change the background color of an entire row in a TABLE chart, based on a column's value?

I tried with no luck to:

- Edit Chart (from a Dashboard)
- Click on one column in the DATA / Query / DIMENSIONS
- In the popup, click on Custom SQL

There is below the **Custom SQL** content:

```
case 
when adate::timestamp < now()
then concat('<img onload="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.background=String.fromCharCode(114)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(100);" src="url_of_a-small_icon">&nbsp;',name)
else name
end
```

-> The goal was to execute a JS line of code to change the entire row's color, see below:

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.style.background='red';
```

NOTE: 'did not manage to escape `'` char so I used `String.fromCharCode(..)`

**RESULT**

The tiny icon from the `<img>` tag plus the column's value are displayed alright.

The row background color was not changed:

- the `onload` event is not found in the final HTML page (anaylzed with JS debugger F12)
- the JS line was not executed.

Q2- How to escape `'` in the Custom SQL, when using `concat` function with mixed `"` and `'`?